# Using the lowercase function with CSV rows

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

I'm trying to print all data from a csv in lowercase, but I'm not having any luck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv
books = csv.reader(open("books.csv","rb"))

for row in books:
    print row
```

This prints all the content of the csv, but when I add the `.lower()` function, I get errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
print [r.lower() for r in row]
```

Comment: Thanks Dogbert! Question - what exactly does the "r" do in this case?

Comment: It's similar to your `for row in books` statement. You can change it to any variable name.

Comment: to make it clear it's equivalent to `print [item.lower() for item in row]` it's just a variable name local to the list comprehension expression (If I'm correct it's local in Python 3.x and declarated after in Python 2.x)