# Edit csv column using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, csv

I would like to make column 2 in the csv file to be all lowercase and removing all the punctuation and save the file. How can i do that?

```
import re
import csv

with open('Cold.csv', 'rb') as f_input1:
    with open('outing.csv', 'wb') as f_output:

      reader = csv.reader(f_input1)
      writer = csv.writer(f_output)

for row in reader:
      row[1] = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]+', ' ', str(row[1].lower()))
      writer.writerow(row)
f_input1.close()
```

How do i add :

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', str(row))
filewriter.writerow([new_row.lower()])
```

or .lower in this code?

Comment: the file name is in.csv and i want to edit that.

Comment: And what does your code currently do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the lowercase function with CSV rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265648/using-the-lowercase-function-with-csv-rows)

Comment: `f_input1.close()` is not required when using a `with` statement here. Also you would need to indent your `for` loop to the same level as your `reader` and `writer` lines.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your code to modify your cell as follows:

```
import re
import csv

with open('in.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('out.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        row[1] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', row[1].lower())
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

`.lower()` is used to first convert the string to lowercase. Using `with` ensures that your files are both automatically closed at the end.

Note, your regular expression sub should replace any invalid characters with an empty string, e.g. `''`, you currently have it set to be a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the row in place and write it back out

```
with open('Cold.csv', 'rb') as f_input1, open('outing.csv', 'wb') as f_output:

    reader = csv.reader(f_input1)
    writer = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in reader:  
        row[1] = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]+', ' ', str(row[1].lower()))
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Do i have to close the file?

Comment: You don't need to close a file when using `with open()` syntax

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution would be combining these two approaches in you code.

```
import string
s.translate(None, string.punctuation) --> to remove punctuation

##if speed is not an issue
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)


row.lower() --> to convert to lower case
```