# How do I delete a text value from all observations in a column with Python?

Tags: python, string

data looks like;

```
    day value
1    X1   52
2    X2   62
3    X3   44
4    X4   30
5    X9   10
```

**I want to delete 'X' from all observations below the day variable in this dataset. So just keep the numbers. how can I do that?**

Code for R= `str.remove.all(data$day, "X")`

**what about python code for same operation?**

Comment: Your data is not showing can you check the link?

Comment: Which dataset type? Pandas? Pyspark?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column might be the answer youre looking for

Comment: dataset type pandas. link renewed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit csv column using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204277/edit-csv-column-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.thanks

```
 data['day'] =data['day'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('X'))
```